# Implications of not installing packages from source?

Tags: r

Occasionally after `install.packages()`:

> Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)

What are the implications of **not** installing a package that needs compilation from source(s)?

#### What I know so far

I guess it's safer to always select 'Yes', and I suspect this may reinstall (/update) shared libraries or extensions (e.g. c, c++, fortran). Also some very general ideas/advantages listed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152353/302720)

Comment: also with `keep_source=TRUE` has implications for later debugging [SOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934886/how-do-i-keep-source-files-when-using-rs-devtools-library-function-install)